# What is the difference between returning a Widget with and without the "new" keyword in flutter? e.g return Container() and return new Container()

Tags: flutter, dart

In flutter we are able to return a widget with and without the `new` keyword. So what is the difference between

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Container(),
    );
  }
}
```

which has `MaterialApp()` and `Container()` constructor without the `new` keyword

and

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Container(),
    );
  }
}
```

which has `new MaterialApp()` and `new Container()` constructor with the `new` keyword

Answer (score 1):

It does the same thing. From dart2, `new` keyword [is optional](https://medium.com/dartlang/announcing-dart-2-80ba01f43b6#da82)